# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error only with domain name

Tags: node.js

So I am getting the `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error when I type `api.website.com/myroute`

But not when I type

```
ipaddress/myroute
```

I am using a `Windows 2016 VM` to host my website if that helps at all.
When I type the IP address the content header is what I have it set to in the express file on my server so I know its working on some level.

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please have a look [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) module

Comment: I'm already using the cors module